# `decltype`: function return type `T` converted to `T&` for user-defined types (VS2010)

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, decltype

EDIT: GCC compiles it just fine, it's VS2010 issue. Thanks for pointing me to ideone.com!

While trying to compile the following (VS2010):

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename PF01, typename PF02 >
inline auto FCall01( PF01 fCallee, PF02 && fParameter00 ) -> decltype( fCallee( std::forward< PF02 > ( fParameter00 ) ) )
{
 decltype( fCallee( std::forward< PF02 > ( fParameter00 ) ) ) lResult( fCallee( std::forward< PF02 >( fParameter00 ) ) ); // offending line for Foo03

 return ( lResult );
}

int gI = 0;
int & gCI = gI;

struct TA
{
  int mData;
  TA( int fData = 0 ) : mData( fData ) { }
  TA( TA const & fA ) : mData( fA.mData ) { }
};

int Foo00( int & fA ){ return ( fA ); }
int & Foo01( int & ){ return ( gCI ); }
int const & Foo02( int & ){ return ( gCI ); }
TA Foo03( int & fA ){ return ( TA( fA ) ); }

int main( void )
{
  decltype( FCall01( Foo00, gI ) ) l0( FCall01( Foo00, gI ) );
  l0 = -1;
  std::cout << gI << " : " << l0 << std::endl;

  decltype( FCall01( Foo01, gI ) ) l1( FCall01( Foo01, gI ) );
  l1 = -2;
  std::cout << gI << " : " << l1 << std::endl;

  decltype( FCall01( Foo02, gI ) ) l2( FCall01( Foo02, gI ) );
  const_cast< int & > ( l2 ) = -3;
  std::cout << gI << " : " << l2 << std::endl;

  decltype( FCall01( Foo03, gI ) ) l3( FCall01( Foo03, gI ) );
  l3.mData = -4;
  std::cout << gI << " : " << l3.mData << std::endl;

  return ( 0 );
}
```

I get a compiler warning:

```
Warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'TA' to
'TA &'; A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue; see reference to function
template instantiation 'TA &FCall01<TA(__cdecl *)(int &),int&>(PF01,PF02) with
[PF01=TA(__cdecl *)(int &),PF02=int &]' being compiled.
```

Everything is fine for built-in type, but for user-defined type, `decltype(...)` in the template function `FCall` gives me `TA&` instead of `TA`, both as `FCall` return type and local variable in `FCall`.

I don't see logic behind it, and I think Standard says `decltype(f())` should give exactly return type of `f()`. And it works fine for built-in types. Is there some hidden catch for user-defined types or it's just VS2010 playing tricks on me?

P.S. I don't have access to GCC, could someone, please, check if GCC compiles is it without warnings?

Comment: hint: you can always try ideone.com for (a not so recent version of) gcc

Comment: I tried codepad.org - it's didn't accept it. Thank you for the reference, going to try it.

Comment: Everyone has access to GCC - http://ideone.com. :)

Comment: @Xeo Yes, thank you, guys, for ideone.com link. GCC compiles it, must be VS2010 issue... Can I delete question? It seems to be useless now. Or one of you make it an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: VS 11 Developer Preview also compiles it fine, so the seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: @AzzA: the title seems to be easy to search, and since it is a VS2010 bug, you can make it an answer and accept it for future reference. If you really want the question to be closed, you can flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a compiler bug in VS2010. It does not happen in neither GCC (ideone.com) nor Visual C++ 11 Developer Preview.

Thanks to PlasmaHH and Xeo for the link to [ideone.com](http://ideone.com), and Jesse for the info on the bug status in Visual C++ 11 Developer Preview.

EDIT: Just a follow-up: this bug in VS2010 happens when user-defined type has user-defined constructor. If it does not have one (compiler generated default is used), bug does not happen.